# Python get data from keyboard buffer

Tags: python, input, listener, keypress

I want to make a system in python what was listen to keypresses and when I hit **enter** something happens depends on the value of the command I write.

How can I do this?

I try to write this:

```py
import keyboard

def run_buffer(cmd):
    print("\nThe buffer value is: {}, The buffer size is: {}".format(cmd, len(cmd)), end="")

buffer = ""
def on_press(e):
    global buffer
    if e.name == "enter": # When I hit enter I need to run the 'command' and emtpy the buffer.
        run_buffer(buffer)
        buffer = ""
    elif e.name == "backspace":
        buffer = buffer[0:-1]
    elif e.name == "f4":
        print("Asd")
    elif len(e.name) == 1:
        buffer += e.name

keyboard.on_press(on_press)

while True: # This was just for the script has runtime and won't stop immediately.
    a = 0
```

When I run the script sometimes works perfectly, but sometimes it's just too late and the cursor not follow my expectations.

[I get this in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF8Cx.png)

I hope someone can help me :D
Thanks for help, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 x64 and use Jetbrains Pycharm as IDE